# Autoincremental countdown timer doesn't count down unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I have this timer in my unity game that is a simple countdown timer that when certain function is completed reset the time to default and increments the time by 1 seconds. It works fine but when I increment by 3 seconds, it doesn't increment.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;

public class GameLogic : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int[] sequence; //The sequence int array will hold our sequence order
    public int sequenceLength; //The sequenceLength is how long a sequence will be. Everytime the player completes a sequence it goes up one
    public int sequencesPlayedCom; //The sequencesPlayedCom is to measure how many times the computer has pressed the buttons in the current sequence
    public int sequencesPlayedPlayer; //The sequencesPlayedPlayer is to measure how many times the player has pressed the buttons in the current sequence
    public float timeleft = 5.0f;
    public float timecounter;

    public int score; //Each time the player completes a sequence they get +1 onto their score
    public int casualHighScore; //This variable holds the highest score that the player has ever achieved on the casual gamemode
    public int randomizeHighScore; //This variable holds the highest score that the player has ever achieved on the randomize gamemode
    public string gameMode; //This will tell us what game mode the player chose so we can modify the game (casual, randomize)

    //Buttons
    public GameObject greenButton; //This holds the GameObject of our green button, so that the script can send messages over to it
    public GameObject redButton; //This holds the GameObject of our red button, so that the script can send messages over to it
    public GameObject blueButton; //This holds the GameObject of our blue button, so that the script can send messages over to it
    public GameObject yellowButton; //This holds the GameObject of our yellow button, so that the script can send messages over to it

    //UI
    public Text scoreText; //This is the text that is displayed on screen, that tells us our score
    public Text highScoreText; //Just like the score text, but displaying the high score

    //Sounds
    public AudioSource audioSource; //This is the source of which we will play the sequence fail and complete sounds through
    public AudioClip sequenceCompleteSound;
    public AudioClip sequenceFailSound;
    public AudioClip buttonClickSound;


    void Start () //The Start function is called on the frame that the script becomes active
    {
        gameMode = PlayerPrefs.GetString("GameMode"); //We need to access our game mode that the player selected
        casualHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CasualHighScore"); //We need to access our saved score
        randomizeHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("RandomizeHighScore"); 
        audioSource = GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Volume"); //We are setting our volume to the one that we set in the options menu
        sequence = new int[50]; //Here we are defining the sequence array's size
        timecounter = timeleft;
        StartCoroutine(GenerateNextSequence()); //We call the GenerateNextSequence function which randomly selects the next number for the sequence
    }

    void Update () //The Update function is called once per frame
    {
        scoreText.text = "SCORE\n" + score; //Here we are setting what our on screen text will say. The '\n' basically makes a new line
        if(gameMode == "casual"){
            highScoreText.text = "HIGH SCORE\n" + casualHighScore; //Just like the on screen score text, but displaying the high score for the casual gamemode
        }
        else if(gameMode == "randomize"){
            highScoreText.text = "HIGH SCORE\n" + randomizeHighScore; //Just like the on screen score text, but displaying the high score for the randomize gamemode
        }

        timer();
    }

    public void timer()
    {
        if (timecounter > 0)
        {
            timecounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(timecounter);
        } else
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(sequenceFailSound); //Since the player failed the sequence, we need to play the appropriate sound
            SaveScore();
            Application.LoadLevel(0); //Since the player we load up the menu
        }

    }
    IEnumerator GenerateNextSequence ()
    {
        sequencesPlayedCom = 0; //Set the number of times that the computer has clicked a button to 0
        sequencesPlayedPlayer = 0; //Set the number of times that the player has clicked a button to 0

        timecounter = timeleft;
        timecounter = timecounter + 3;

        if (gameMode == "casual"){
            sequence[sequenceLength - 1] = Random.Range(1, 5); //Since array index's start at 0, we have it randomly select a number between 1 and 5 (it rounds to the nearest int) and set it to the most current index number.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //We wait 1 second after picking our next colour, before going on to playing the sequence
            StartCoroutine(PlaySequence()); //Now that we have our next colour, we can go and play the array to the player
        }
        else if(gameMode == "randomize"){
            for(int i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i ++){
                sequence[i] = Random.Range(1, 5);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            StartCoroutine(PlaySequence()); //Now that we have our random sequence, we can have the computer play it
        }
    }

    IEnumerator PlaySequence () //Plays the sequence
    {   
        CanClickButton(false); //We call a function that disables the buttons while the computer is playing the sequence

        while(sequencesPlayedCom < sequenceLength){ //A while loop. Here we have it continuously do what is inside the brackets as long as sequencesPlayedCom < sequenceLength
            GameObject buttonToPress = null; //We set this temporary GameObject variable to hold the button so its ButtonPress function can be called

            if(sequence[sequencesPlayedCom] == 1){ //If the next element in the int array is 1 then it will be a green button
                buttonToPress = greenButton;
            }
            else if(sequence[sequencesPlayedCom] == 2){
                buttonToPress = redButton;
            }
            else if(sequence[sequencesPlayedCom] == 3){
                buttonToPress = blueButton;
            }
            else if(sequence[sequencesPlayedCom] == 4){
                buttonToPress = yellowButton;
            }

            buttonToPress.SendMessage("ButtonPress"); //We call the ButtonPress function on the button so the player can see and hear it
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f); //Wait 0.7 seconds until we continue to the next colour in the sequence
            sequencesPlayedCom++; //Adding one to the sequencesPlayedCom so we know that computer just clicked a button
        }

        if(sequencesPlayedCom == sequenceLength){
            CanClickButton(true); //After the computer has pressed all the buttons in the sequence, the player can now click on the buttons
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CheckSequenceButton (int id)
    {   
        if(sequence[sequencesPlayedPlayer] == id){ //We check to see if the next color of the sequence is the one that the player pressed
            sequencesPlayedPlayer ++;
        }else{
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f); 
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(sequenceFailSound); //Since the player failed the sequence, we need to play the appropriate sound

            SaveScore();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.7f); //A delay after the player fails 
            Application.LoadLevel(0); //Since the player we load up the menu
        }

        if(sequencesPlayedPlayer == sequenceLength){ //If the player has completed the sequence
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f); //We have a small delay after the player completes the sequence
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(sequenceCompleteSound);
            score++; //Since the player has completed the sequence, we will add 1 to the score
            sequenceLength++; //The sequence length is one added to it
            StartCoroutine(GenerateNextSequence()); //We continue on with this loop, increasing the sequence one colour at a time
        }
    }

    public void GoToMenu () //Function used to get back to the main menu    
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(buttonClickSound); //Playing the button click sound
        SaveScore();
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }

    void CanClickButton (bool i) //Tells the buttons if they can be clicked or not
    {
        greenButton.SendMessage("DisableOrEnableButton", i);
        redButton.SendMessage("DisableOrEnableButton", i);
        blueButton.SendMessage("DisableOrEnableButton", i);
        yellowButton.SendMessage("DisableOrEnableButton", i);
    }

    void SaveScore () //Checks if score is higher that high score then saves it to Player Prefs
    {
        if(gameMode == "casual"){ //If the game mode is Casual 
            if(score > casualHighScore){ //If the players current score is higher than their highscore then we will change it
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CasualHighScore", score);
                if (PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated)
                {
                    // Note: make sure to add 'using GooglePlayGames'
                    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ReportScore(score,
                        GPGSlds.leaderboard_facil,
                        (bool success) =>
                        {
                            Debug.Log("(Lollygagger) Leaderboard update success: " + success);
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        else if(gameMode == "randomize"){
            if(score > randomizeHighScore){
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("RandomizeHighScore", score);
                if (PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated)
                {
                    // Note: make sure to add 'using GooglePlayGames'
                    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ReportScore(score,
                        GPGSlds.leaderboard_normal,
                        (bool success) =>
                        {
                            Debug.Log("(Lollygagger) Leaderboard update success: " + success);
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I miss some code that doesn't have to do with the timer, the timer work fine, just that I can't do the autoincrement when the function `GenerateNextSequence()` is run.

Comment: The IEnumerator doesn´t yield and don´t have any sense

Comment: thats because i remove some code that doesnt have to do with the timer, the complete code has a yield return new

Comment: It's hard to help you when we see only a some part of code, how we can be sure that you didn't make a mistake it that part of code you hiding from us?

Comment: ready i edit and put the complete code

Comment: @hastati that is now too much code, you need to create a new [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the same problem in less code. You should post something we can just copy the text of and paste in to our own project with no to minimal extra work and see the same issue on our machine.